# Jquery AJAX query overriding previous AJAX new query

Tags: jquery, ajax, overriding

I have this problem with $.ajax() in JQuery. Where old ajax queries override the newer ajax query.

I am implementing a website, when the user change the filter parameter, the listing will update accordingly.

So the logic is this:

1. User select filter option
2. AJAX query made. Once the request is completed asynchronously, refresh the listing to the newer one.

The problem arises when user filter very quickly.
1. User filter criteria A at time T
2. AJAX request made to backend server, assume it takes 5s to response and return.
3. By then user filter criteria B T+1s.
4. AJAX request made to backend server, assume it take 500ms to response and return.
5. From step 4, my listing will be updated with criteria A
6. However, after step 2 is completed in 5s, the response return and my listing is updated with the older criteria A!!

This is a big problem I have whenever I do AJAX. anyone can help with this? Is there an option to ignore the older request?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am assuming that there is one AJAX posting the whole form which looks something like this:

```
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
```

All you do is add a variable outside your function, eg:

```
var started = false;

/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
    if(!started)
    {
        started = true;

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

        /* Put the results in a div */
        posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
        $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
        });

        started = false;
    }

});
```

It then checks if it is running first before ajaxing it again, remember to set started to false when done.

Comment: Also considering disabling the form while it is busy loading

Comment: thanks we0! But i would not want to restrict user from sending a new ajax request while the previous one is not completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the previous ajax request by calling abort() method

```
var filterRequest= $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some Url",
data: "{}",
success: function(response){
   alert( "Response recieved: " + response );
}});
```

Cancel request:

```
filterRequest.abort();
```

Comment: So in your case before sending a new filter request you have to call filterRequest.abort(); this will cancel previous request if exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem using time stamp.

First upon loading the document, set the timestamp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.TIMESTAMP = Date();//initialize with current datetime
}

/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  var time_sent = new Date();

  /*only if the time_sent is later than the TIMESTAMP
  if (time_sent > Date(window.TIMESTAMP)){
      /* Send the data using post */
      var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

      /* Put the results in a div */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
        $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
        //update the time stamp
        window.TIMESTAMP = time_sent;
      });
    });
  }
```